# Can I control 2 Bootstrap Carousels with one set of controllers?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have two sliding carousels side by side and i want to control them with one set of controls. My main goal is to have one carousel with two carousels in it and change the direction/animation of one of them to make something cool. I have tried this is my curent code:

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <div class="kampany">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="kampanyapic px-0">
                        <div id="kampanyacontrol" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                              <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517994112540-009c47ea476b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9" alt="First slide">
                              </div>
                              <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494905998402-395d579af36f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9" alt="Second slide">
                              </div>
                              <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503736334956-4c8f8e92946d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9" alt="Third slide">
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#kampanyacontrol" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                            </a>
                            
                          </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="kampanyainfo px-0">
                        <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                                          <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517994112540-009c47ea476b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9" alt="First slide">
                              </div>
                              <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494905998402-395d579af36f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9" alt="Second slide">
                              </div>
                              <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503736334956-4c8f8e92946d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9" alt="Third slide">
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                            </a>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I have tried to changing `href`s to class but i failed miserably. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using selective triggering adding the snippet as illustrated below:

```
$('.kampany .carousel-control-next,.kampany .carousel-control-prev').on('click', function (e) {
      var inst = $(this).data("slide");
      if(inst== "prev"){ 
      $("#carouselExampleControls").carousel("prev")}
      else{ $("#kampanyacontrol").carousel("next")}
    })
```

The full solution will be:

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <div class="kampany">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="kampanyapic px-0">
                        <div id="kampanyacontrol" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                              <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517994112540-009c47ea476b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9" alt="First slide">
                              </div>
                              <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494905998402-395d579af36f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9" alt="Second slide">
                              </div>
                              <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503736334956-4c8f8e92946d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9" alt="Third slide">
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#kampanyacontrol" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                            </a>
                            
                          </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="kampanyainfo px-0">
                        <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                                          <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517994112540-009c47ea476b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9" alt="First slide">
                              </div>
                              <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494905998402-395d579af36f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9" alt="Second slide">
                              </div>
                              <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503736334956-4c8f8e92946d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9" alt="Third slide">
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                            </a>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

   <script>
 $('.kampany .carousel-control-next,.kampany .carousel-control-prev').on('click', function (e) {
          var inst = $(this).data("slide");
          if(inst== "prev"){ 
          $("#carouselExampleControls").carousel("prev")}
          else{ $("#kampanyacontrol").carousel("next")}
        })
</script>
```

Comment: It totally works, I think I just burned out from this project and couldn't think anything. Thank you so much!